# Can I use Android's Holo theme on versions earlier than Ice Cream Sandwich?

Tags: themes

I have recently used Ice Cream Sandwich and I really like the Holo theme. I would like to be able to use this theme for lower Android API versions (Gingerbread, Froyo, Eclair, etc). Is there a way to port this theme to older versions of Android, or any other way that I could use it?

Comment: You're looking for a theming engine for this to make it look like ICS ?

Comment: yes, did you know one?

Comment: a lot of apps on my Gingerbread devices use the holo theme, so I'd answer this with a clear "Yes". But if your question is about how to integrate it with an app you develop, I'd suggest you flag your question to be migrated to stackoverflow (as development questions are off-topic here).

Answer (score 1):

There are Holo themes available for the T-Mobile/CyanogenMod Theme Chooser. If you have the theme chooser you just download a Holo theme from the market select it.

You can find out more about CyanogenMod (has the theme chooser built in) [here](http://cyanogenmod.com).